# Using pygame on mac, strange errors

Tags: pygame, macos

I am using pygame on a mac, and when the app runs, it draws a frame of the screen fine, and then crashes with the following error:

```
Assertion failed: (NSViewIsCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay() != currentlyBuildingLayerTree), 
function NSViewSetCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay, 
file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1561.10.101/AppKit.subproj/NSView.m, 
line 14480.
```

Everything was working fine, but I did switch to multi-threading, and I think this might be related.  Has anyone a clue as to what might be going wrong?

I call:

```
pygame.init()
pygame_size = 1280, 960  # image dimensions
pygame_screen = pygame.display.set_mode(pygame_size)
```

in the main thread, and then I have many pygame draw calls.

Comment: Do you touch any pygame functions from a non-main thread?

Comment: Yes.  So, Thinking this might be the problem now.  I am actually using it as part of running tests and trying to save screen captures of the tests.  I am not actually trying to run a multi-threaded game.

Comment: YES! I moved the screen creation into the main thread, and now it is not crashing!